# Приложение требует разрешения Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, google-play

Игра созданная на Unity3d при запуске требует 2 разрешения:

**android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE --
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS**

В игре используется Google Play Services и 3 сторонних ассета из Asset Store, поэтому допустим GET_ACCOUNTS если я правильно понимаю используется для achiviements, leaderboard и т.п. Но почему нужен доступ к READ_PHONE_STATE я так и не понял.
Данные разрешения игра спрашивала до установки и настройки Google Play Services, и все 3 сторонних ассета сугубо внутренне игровые (первый для заднего фона, второй для управления touch и третий для object pooling).
Я проверил Android Manifest и не нашел там ни одного упоминания об этих двух функциях.
Подскажите может ли быть такое что в этих 3 сторонних ассетах что - то обращается к данным функциям? Или Google SDK по дефолту обращается к подобным штукам?

Answer (score 1):

Если есть Google Services, то по логике READ_PHONE_STATE должен быть, чтобы проверять наличие соединения с интернетом.На андроид игры не делал, но судя по инфе с оф.сайта так и есть.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html
Не точно.

> Allows read only access to phone state, including the current cellular network information, the status of any ongoing calls, and a list of any PhoneAccounts registered on the device.

Гугл перевод:

> Разрешает доступ только для чтения к состоянию телефона, включая текущую информацию о сотовой сети, статус любых текущих вызовов и список "PhoneAccounts", зарегистрированных на устройстве.